# Windows 2003 Server, Parallels, Plesk, Php5 and mail()

Tags: windows-server-2003, php, iis-6

I'm running Parallels with Windows 2003 Server Plesk on my VPS and I can't send mails via mail()

Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 550 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable or not local (...)

Relay options
[link text](http://img198.imageshack.us/i/pleskmailsettings.jpg/)

```
Php.ini
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
```

Any ideeas what can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make that error go away by making a mail address in the Plesk panel for the domain where I was running the script.
i.e.  Script was at http://www.phpdomainname.com/mailtest.php

In the Plesk control panel for phpdomainname.com, I opened the "Mail" icon and created an account called postmaster (postmaster@phpdomainname.com).
Then in the php script, I changed the value of the 'from' variable to postmaster@phpdomainname.com and the error went away

Still can't send mail with the script, but it doesnt return the 'not local' error.  Now troubleshooting why mail still doesn't go out, which is how I ran across your question.

- k -